How to return multiple listings based on the criteria
I have an Action [HttpGet] that returns all entries from a class Services and Status , schema similar to this
"hstryTimeStamp": "string",
    "hstryDateTime": "2024-04-25T23:17:44.955Z",
    "ServiceName": "string",
    "mobilePhone": "string",
    "ethnicity": "string",
    "Status": [
      {
        "statusSer": 0,
        "ServiceSer": 0,
        "statusId": "string",
        "startDateTime": "2024-04-25T23:17:44.955Z",
        "Status": "string",
    

Above code is working, now I would like to search by Status  (e.g. "Running” /”Stopped”).
How do I get all records where Status is “Running” and its “ServiceName”
I’ve tried this but this returns one entry
//action Get By Status
[HttpGet("{Status}")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Statu), StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(Statu), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetByStatus(string Status)
{
    var _status = Convert.ToString(Status);
    var status = await _context.Courses.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.Status == _status );
    return status == null ? NotFound() : Ok(status);
}

